# What is the point of the XNA.Input.Button enum?

Tags: xna, c#

I am trying to make an `InputManager` class that will let me basically bridge XNA's various input methods and do a corresponding action in my game. Part of this is designing different keybindings.

Suppose I have a class `GamePadBinding : InputBinding<Button>` - this is the `Button` enum from XNA.Input and has a variety of different buttons (Left, A, etc). However, to actually check input, I have to call something like `if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed)`, and the problem with that is that it uses a struct with readonly values.

How am I expected to store an enum of type `Button` and compare that with this? I really am not seeing the point of this enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the button state easier using the `GamePadState.IsButtonUp` and `GamePadState.IsButtonDown` methods. These both accept an `Input.Buttons` parameter.

See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepadstate.isbuttonup%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx).